# How can I export mongodb query results to an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
function findListNames() {
  var listeler = [];
  List.find({}, async function(err, foundLists) {
    await foundLists.forEach(isim => {
      listeler.push(isim);
    });
  });
  console.log(listeler);
  return listeler;
};
```

I want to keep the names of data in a database in an array. I made a function for this, but I cannot send the data I receive to the empty list. Can you help me?

i see the query results in find() function. But i cant throw it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toArray()` :

```js
async function findListNames() {
  const cursor = List.find({});
  const result = await cursor.toArray();
  const listeler = result.map(item => item.isim);
  console.log(listeler);
  return listeler;
};
```

Comment: thanks body, toArray() is doesn't work effectively in latest version